# Passing variable arguments from python using ctypes function call to C++ function

Tags: c++, python, linux, python-2.7, ctypes

I have a problem when I pass variable arguments to `ctypes` function from HTML/JS->python in pyramid f/w -->C++

For example, my HTTP GET call wil be as below:

> type: "GET",      async:   false,
>           url: "/web/NewModel/getValues?count=2&parameters=Param1,Param2",
>           success: function(data){
>               alert(data.GetValue)

Python base code:

```
def get_Multiple_Xpaths(request):
    count = int(request.params['count'])
    requests=[]
    requests = request.params['parameters'].split(',')
    print 'count:%s' % (count)
    data=wrapperClass.getMultipleValues(count , *requests)
    print 'Final Data:%s' % (data)
    return {'Get':data}
```

I/F Python between Python and C++:

```
from ctypes import *
so = cdll.LoadLibrary(***)
funcHandle = so.CallC++Function
funcHandle.restype = c_char_p
def getMultipleValues(cls, count, *args):
        print 'count:%s' % (count)
        print 'Length of tuple:%s' %str(len(args))
        for a in args:
            print 'Wrapper Param:%s' % (a)
        value=funcHandle(count, "Find" , *args) -->C++ debug prints parameters as empty. I tried to use str(*args) but it works only if `*args` actually has 1 argument. For multiple, it throws a type error.

        print 'Wrapper Value:%s' % (value)  ---->Returns Empty
        return value
```

The problem seems to be when I pass `*args` between 2 Python functions, it is getting the values fine *(when I print the values in getMultipleValues Function it prints fine)*. However the `funcHandle` Call which I use, the C++ doesnt get any value for `*args` which is being passed.

If I run a test program with `funcHandle(count, "Find" , "parameter1" , "parameter2")`, it gets the values fine.

Please advice me on what I am doing wrong here. My requirement is to pass the function with variable number of arguments as mentioned in the previous line so that C++ functions can access and process whatever it needs to.

Comment: Did you try `args` rather than `*args`?

Comment: I tried but same result. if i give args it mentions TypeError.

Comment: This is the error i get when i pass args instead of *args(ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 3)

Comment: from ctypes import *  
printf = cdll.msvcrt.printf  
printf("%f %s %s\n", c_double(10.1), *("123", "234"))  
This works fine so I think there may be some problem about your data.

Comment: I tried to copy args to an array and pass the array. This works. But strangely args which is actually expanded to a list doesnt work.